# html strip the protocol from the string https:// javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have html that reads

```
<a class="Test" ng-href="{{d.link}}">link</a>
```

So my d.link equals to eg. (google.com) ng-href will not take me to it since its not https://

so my logical explanation would be to add `ng-href="https://{{d.link}}"`

but then if my d.link is https://google.com then my ng-href will be https://https://google.com.. Do i need to go to JS or this can be solved in html?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you enforce `d.link` to use one format or the other rather than trying to deal with both simultaneously. That's a design flaw and is severely bug-prone if you just try to "solve" it using HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: So js it is Patrick :)

Comment: change the value of `d.link`... btw you can leave off the protocol and just start the uri with `//google.com` ..that way it will automatically choose whether to use https depending on whether the current page uses it..

Answer (score 0):

You can leave it for the browser to decide what protocol to use, so your code will be like this: `ng-href="//{{d.link}}"`

Just try it, hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: he's saying the protocol is already included in the variable.. so using your suggesting his attribute would be `//http://google.....`

Comment: @Occam'sRazor Whoops, so he has to go with JS solution and has to strip out protocol using JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you so desire...

```
{{"//"+d.link.replace(/^(http|https):\/\/(.+)/,"$2")}}
```

This removes the http:// or https:// from a given string using Regex. The $2 is the second set () of parenthesis, also known as a capture group.

Comment: maybe you meant `d.link = d.link.replace(/http[s]?:/,"")`

Comment: Maybe OP meant that too, but we'll probably never know.

Comment: your answer now accounts for the optional `s` and uses the second match, so that's better, but still not correct. the url needs to start with `//` if it is a url from another domain, otherwise it will assume `google.com` is a relative url take him to `http://his-domain.com/google.com`.. best way to do it is just to remove an http or an https if it exists.

Comment: open your console and type `window.location.href = "google.com"` and see what happens